# Using web.py to dynamically output values from process initiated by form submission

Tags: python, web.py

I'm new to web servers, so I need some guidance as to how to achieve the following:

1. User that's on the same network as server opens a page on the server (eg 10.42.68.130:8080/cycle).
2. User is presented with a form, that asks him to enter a number of cycles.
3. User clicks submit. The submission activates another function that executes a for-loop the specified number of times (I simplified all of this, so it's really supposed to fire GPIO pins on a beaglebone black)
4. The user receives progress feedback, so a counter that shows how many cycles have been completed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm going off the tutorials in learnpythonthehardway.com lessons 50 and 51. This is what I managed to get going.

bin/app.py

```
import web
import time

urls = ('/cycle', 'Index')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form2()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(cycles=0)
        cycleparams = "%s" % (form.cycles)
        cycleGPIO(form.cycles)
        return render.index2(cycleparams = cycleparams)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

def cycleGPIO(cycles):
    for i in range(int(cycles)):
        print "cycle " + str(i+1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

templates/layout.html

```
$def with (content)

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

$:content

</body>
</html>
```

templates/index2.html

```
$def with (cycleparams)

$if cycleparams:
    Test completed with the following parameters:
    <br> 
    $cycleparams
$else:
    No parameters specified
<br><br>
<a href="/cycle">Return to form</a>
```

templates/hello_form2.html

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Output Cycling</legend>

<form action="/cycle" method="POST">
    <br>Number of cycles:
    <br><input type="number" name="cycles">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this issue is to separate your web and GPIO cycle processes. After this you can use one of the many interprocess communication mechanisms available in python. A good page to read about this is [Interprocess Communication and Networking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html).

For now, I'll just pick an easiest way to communicate between two python processes, a plain text file. We'll have two files. One that your web service process will use to send your form input to GPIO process, and another one that GPIO process will use to send feedback to the web service.

Please remember that this is only an example, and there are many many better ways to solve interprocess communication problem. This is just here to give you a rough idea, and not something that you should use in any production systems.

This is how code could look like.

web.py service changes

```
...

urls = ('/cycle-status', 'StatusIndex')

...

class StatusIndex(object):
    def GET(self):
        # Read feedback params from a file
        cycleparams = read_gpio_feedback_file()
        return render.index2(cycleparams = cycleparams)

class Index(object):

    ...

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(cycles = 0)
        cycleparams = "%s" % (form.cycles)
        # Write cycle params to a file
        write_cycle_params(form.cycles)
        # This call probably won't produce any results 
        # because your GPIO process couldn't react so fast. 
        return render.index2(cycleparams = {})

def write_cycle_params(cycles):
    f = open('/path/to/cycles/file.txt', 'w')
    for i in range(int(cycles)):
        f.write("cycle " + str(i + 1))
    f.close()

def read_gpio_feedback():
    cycleparams = {}
    f = open('/path/to/feedback/file.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        cycleparams['param1'] = line
    f.close()
    return cycleparams
```

GPIO process

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cycleparams = ""
    f = open('/path/to/cycles/file.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        cycleparams = cycleparams + line
    f.close()

    # Do something with cycleparams related to GPIO
    # Get your cycle params from GPIO pins

    ...

    cycleparams = ""

    f = open('/path/to/feedback/file.txt','w')
    f.write(cycleparams + '\n')
    f.close()

    sys.exit(0)
```

Your GPIO process will have to run periodically to read info from the web service generated file, and also to write feedback that web service will parse and display output. You can achieve this by adding GPIO process into crontab (or any other process scheduling mechanism will work fine).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer Boris! I'll definitely go through that link you provided shortly and will split the server and GPIO process. One thing that I see you doing in your code is rerendering the page every time there's new feedback from the server to the client. I can't seem to figure out how to output to a page without rendering the whole thing with updated information each time.

Comment: There are two ways to accomplish that. One is long polling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling, and the other one is to push your data from server to client (web browser) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29. In both cases you will have to maintain long running connections between client and server, and they both require client side JavaScript code. This blog has some good code examples http://blog.oddbit.com/2013/11/23/long-polling-with-ja/.